# ASP.Net MVC "Magic Strings" - Can they be avoided?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ok take this example below:

```
public ActionResult ViewProfile()
{
    //Load the profile for the currently logged in user
    if (Membership.GetUser() != null)
    {
        //Do some stuff get some data.
        return View(ReturnViewModel);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("MainLogon", "Logon");
}
```

Is there anyway to avoid the "magic strings" when redirecting to the Logon page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would not go near MVC Futures in this case.

I would recommend using T4MVC

David Ebbo talks about it here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2009/06/17/a-new-and-improved-asp-net-mvc-t4-template.aspx

With an updated version here also including refactoring support for action methods:

http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2009/06/26/the-mvc-t4-template-is-now-up-on-codeplex-and-it-does-change-your-code-a-bit.aspx

Means that instead of using a literal like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("DinnerForm"); %>
```

You can now make use of intellisense and strongly type it:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Dinners.Views.DinnerForm); %>
```

This has also been blogged about by Scott Hanselman here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode43ASPNETMVCAndT4AndNerdDinner.aspx

Comment: Note: The project has moved from CodePlex to github.

https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC

Answer (score 1):

(1). There is a way to use strongly typed methods. They were once in ASP.NET MVC preview, but were removed from the release and put into MVC Futures

Something like:

```
Html.ActionLink<HomeController>(c => c.Index(), "Home")
```

(2). Define constants for all actions and use them.

Comment: Note that the futures helpers have something on the order of 10* worse performance than the standard helpers and don't work with ActionNameAttribute.